# Improving a GET request using the default Go HTTP client

Tags: rest, go

I'd like to improve the [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) request that I'm using in a function using the [net/http](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http) package in Go.

I'm using `bodyText, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)` in the function, but I'm not sure if this is the best way to get the JSON response from the server.

```
// Getting HTTP Status code
func StatusF (url string, token string) *statusf {
    // Setup req
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    req.Header.Set("Authorization", token)

    // Request
    resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Close response
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    // Getting the response from the server
    bodyText, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    fmt.Printf("response:%s", bodyText)

    var myvar StructureJson // we create an empty instance of StructureJson
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(bodyText), &myvar)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Return the JSON object
    return &myvar
}
```

Comment: If you plan to unmarshal the whole body, it's more efficient to create a `json.Decoder` from the body, and use its `Decode()` method. That way you avoid the intermediate `bodyText` buffer.

Comment: @icza Theoretically with that HTTP GET request i'm only getting the JSON info that I specified on my original question, right (no headers, etc)? Also, if I include Decode(), may you please let me know how you would modify the code to include it? just to avoid any confusion.

Comment: `err := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&myvar)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments if I want to improve the function I can include `err := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&myvar)` and delete the intermediate `bodyText` buffer:

```
// Getting HTTP Status code
func StatusF (url string, token string) *statusf {
    // Setup req
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    req.Header.Set("Authorization", token)

    // Request
    resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Close response
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    var myvar StructureJson // we create an empty instance of StructureJson
    err := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&myvar)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // return the JSON object
    return &myvar
}
```